# ecryptfs - relation of user entered passphrase to the FEKEK when mounting manually

Tags: encryption, ecryptfs

I've been trying to set up encrypted folder following the instructions in https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/ECryptfs#Without_ecryptfs-utils. In that case a mount passphrase is manually created and wrapped using a chosen password ("Arch" in that example). This is working as expected.

There is yet another possibility how to manually set up things. Namely using simple mount e.g.:
mount -t ecryptfs ~/.Private/ ~/Private -o key=passphrase,ecryptfs_cipher=aes,ecryptfs_key_bytes=32,ecryptfs_passthrough=n,ecryptfs_enable_filename_crypto=y

In this case I'm prompted for a [password] and after that folder is mounted.

My question is: where is the mount passphrase hidden in the second example? And how is my entered [password] related to it and to the FEKEK in this case.

Could anybody please explain?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think the entered passphrase becomes the *"file encryption key, encryption key, or FEKEK"* itself, and is temporarily stored in the kernel keyring (root's keyring if you need to mount with `sudo`) while the folder is mounted. You can see the keyring before & after mounting & unmounting with `sudo keyctl show`.

It does not store the passphrase/FEKEK anywhere on disk, unlike the method "Without ecryptfs-utils" in the ArchWiki you liked to, and the one in the ecryptfs-utils below.

---

FYI, using the ecryptfs-utils tools it will create a random (16 byte) passphrase to use, if you haven't specified your own passphrase, and it apparently is the file encryption key (FEKEK) / FNEK.

Looking in a couple of the ecryptfs-utils tools, (several are shell scripts) inside `ecryptfs-migrate-home` it collects some data and calls `ecryptfs-setup-private`, which has this function to generate a more secure 16 byte random passphrase/FEKEK/FNEK (that then gets "wrapped"/encrypted with your login passphrase and stored on disk):

```
random_passphrase () {
        bytes=$1
        # Pull $1 of random data from /dev/urandom,
        # and convert to a string of hex digits
        od -x -N $bytes --width=$bytes /dev/urandom | head -n 1 | sed "s/^0000000//" | sed "s/\s*//g"
}
```